# Why does self appear to be nil here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, ruby-2.0

Inside a model, I have the following:

```
after_create :send_to_user
def send_to_user
    puts "self before if is #{self.inspect}"
    if self.non_user_email
        puts "self after if is #{@self.inspect}"
        @document = self.document
        @email = self.non_user_email
        ...
    end
end
```

For some reason, the first `puts` knows what `self` is but the second `puts` is showing up as nil:

```
self before if is 
#<Transaction id: 6, document_id: 2, buyer_id: nil, amount: nil, created_at: "2016-01-18 23:58:43", updated_at: "2016-01-18 23:58:43", author_id: 1, non_user_email: "pghrpg@gmail.com">
self after if is nil
```

how is this possible?

Comment: In the second `puts` statement, you're using `@self` instead of `self`. Voting to close as "typo."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're giving the second `puts` an instance variable named `@self` when you should be sending it just `self`. Instance variables (variables that begin with `@`) default to `nil`. You just need to get rid of that extra @ in front of self, like this:

```
puts "self after if is #{self.inspect}"
```